# Show error page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, custom-error-pages

How can I show custom error pages in codeigniter.

Ex : There are some problems with database , I want to show a custom made error page instead of the default one.

I dont want to use some codes when some error occures ,I need to set up this by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**APPLICATION_PATH/application/errors** here you can find all the error pages you can edit them as per your requirements.